# Searching URL within the string

Tags: java, regex, url

I have following function

```
private static String changeUrl(String text) {    

        String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while(m.find()) {
            // get whole matching
            String urlStr = m.group();

            if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")")) {
                urlStr = urlStr.substring(1, urlStr.length() - 1);
            }


            System.out.println(urlStr);

            return text;
    }
```

It works fine, and prints URLs, but it could not find URL in the form

- `/example.com/something/sdfs/sdf/skdjf.sdfj`
- `/something/sdfs/sdf/skdjf.sdfj`

I can change the pattern, but I am new to regex, and don't want to make side effects. So is there a tested regex pattern which will identify all possibilities?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just split by spaces and use the `URI` class? It is much more efficient than a regex and does not leave room for errors, unlike a regex

Comment: @fge, could you please explain you approach in more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Not without further details; for instance why the initial `(`? If it exists, do you also expect an ending `)`?

Comment: @fge, no actually I just copied this example, the problem is, I need to find all URLs inside some string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to add `/` as another option as start of url. To do this you can change

```
(http://|www[.])
```

part to something like

```
(http://|www[.]|/)
```

---

I would also instead of regex  consider using `URI` `URL` or `File` classes to handle such data, but since I don't know how you are using this regex (some more input examples would be helpful) it is hard for me to say something more on this subject.

Comment: one more thing, why it is starting with `\\` characters, as I know it is escaping \`\\` symbol, but why it is required? Thank you

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing how you are using this method/regex. Also code you have posted seems not full and doesn't compile which also doesn't make your question easier to answer.

Comment: @akmal Anyway `(` is regex special character so if you would like to match `(` in string you will have to escape it with `\(` but since we are writing this regex as String (where ``\`` is also special) we need to also escape it there which leaves us with `"\\(..."`. I assume that your data are placed in parenthesis and regex is trying to find it if it is link.

Comment: @Pshermo, one more thing related to usage, the input for this function is script enclosed in `<script> </script>` tags, so first I parse an HTML using `jsoup` to get the content of these tags, and then send it to this function. So this function is looking for URL within script and changes it. I think the best way to do this is using `regex`, or there is a better approach? Thank you.

Comment: @akmal I not use JS often so I don't know how to do it better yet, but I would start by searching some `JS parser` since regex can fail in many cases like URLs placed in `(...)` but written in comments

Comment: @akmal This question seems interesting, but I am not sure if asking to recommend parser on SO is good idea. You can try but I am afraid your question will be put on hold as off topic. You could try asking on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be precise what you need.